# JWT: Authentication in slim v3 and Android

Tags: android, jwt, restful-authentication, slim-3

I am using Slim framework to return JSON to my Android device. I am currently working on login on my device. I am using 3 different ways to login: Facebook, Google and account login. When he takes account login he can register a new account or login with an existing one.

For security on my web service I thought to use JWT security. So I am reading and watching video's about how it works. I think I understand how it works, but I cannot find anything about how to implement it correctly.

The middleware I use for slim v3 is called: [Slim-JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth).
I found the [following link](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth) to implement this in my slim framework, and it works correctly I think.

**Now my questions:**

1. *How do I generate my Token?*
2. *When do I generate my Token?*
3. *Do I also need a Token when using Google or Facebook sign-in? because they already use a Auth2.0 token?*

I understand how it works but nobody is talking about when and how to implement it. So when do I need to generate the token (on login on the webservice?), and do I need to generate a token after every start of the app, or do I just need to wait until the token expires?

Comment: If you need more info, or a sample please let me know.

Comment: I think that you should generate the token whenever the user logs in through an account (if she uses Google or Facebook sign-in you should verify its validity by calling some Google/Facebook API, I guess), pass it to the client (e.g. like a session cookie) and validate it to ensure it's valid. For question 2, you can use one of several PHP libraries to generate the JWT (check on [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/)), and you **MUST NOT** include sensitive data inside the token since it is **not encrypted** (it is only Base64URL encoded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How do I generate my Token?**

Since the middleware already includes [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library you can use it to generate the token.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future = new DateTime("now +2 hours");
$server = $request->getServerParams();
$payload = [
    "iat" => $now->getTimeStamp(),
    "exp" => $future->getTimeStamp(),
    "sub" => $server["PHP_AUTH_USER"]
];

$secret = "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub";
$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret, "HS256");
```

**When do I generate my Token?**

In your api you can for example include a password protected route which returns the token. All other routes except `/token` are JWT authenticated. Client can request token with every request or just always bit before the old one expires.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/token",
    "users" => [
        "test" => "test"
    ]
]);

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub"
    "rules" => [
        new RequestPathRule([
            "path" => "/",
            "passthrough" => ["/token"]
        ])
    ]
]);

$app->post("/token", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {

    $now = new DateTime();
    $future = new DateTime("now +2 hours");
    $server = $request->getServerParams();

    $payload = [
        "iat" => $now->getTimeStamp(),
        "exp" => $future->getTimeStamp(),
        "sub" => $server["PHP_AUTH_USER"],
    ];
    $secret = "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub";
    $token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret, "HS256");
    $data["status"] = "ok";
    $data["token"] = $token;

    return $response->withStatus(201)
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
});
```

**Do I also need a Token when using Google or Facebook sign-in? because they already use a Auth2.0 token?**

There is no clear answer to this. It "depends". You could for example authenticate your `/token` route with Facebook or Google and return your own JWT token from there.

There is an work in progress more detailed [example implementation](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-api-skeleton) of everything above you might want to check.