# HTTP Basic Authentication fails with Slim 3 using PDO Authenticator

Tags: php, pdo, slim, basic-authentication

I am using Slim v 3 with JWT for writing REST APIs. I followed https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth and it is working fine.

I am generating a token each time the user logs into the appl. To authenticate the user, I followed https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth to use as auth middleware. On success, I am generating a token using https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt.

I was going through a related question on SO here, [JWT: Authentication in slim v3 and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749646/jwt-authentication-in-slim-v3-and-android) and I have a query on http basic auth. (I dont have sufficient rep to make a comment there ).

**Now my questions:**

1. HttpBasicAuthentication through the 'users' option is working fine but I wouldnt be able to use it against my users table obviously. Many users would be logging into the application and listing all of them in the 'users' is not an option. Am I right here?
2. If yes, I have to use Pdo Authenticator. I configured it but authentication is failing and I couldnt solve it. The error callback is being fired with "Authentication failed" message. My database has 'users' table with 'user' and 'hash' columns for username and password. Below is the piece of code I am using.

> ```
> use Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication;
> use Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication\PdoAuthenticator;
> ```

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $dbUser, $dbPassword);

$middlewareHttpBasicAuthConfig = [
        /*"users" => [
            "user1" => "password"
        ],*/
        "secure" => false,
        "relaxed" => ["localhost", "amruta-pani"],
        "path" => "/*",
        "passthrough" => Utils::httpAuthPassThroughRoutes,
        "realm" => "Protected",

        "authenticator" => new PdoAuthenticator([
            "pdo" => $pdo
        ]),

        "callback" => function($request, $response, $arguments) {
            echo "Through<br>\n";
            print_r($arguments);
        },

        "error" => function($request, $response, $arguments) {
            echo "Failed<br>\n";
            print_r($arguments);
        }
    ];


    $app->add(new HttpBasicAuthentication($middlewareHttpBasicAuthConfig));
```

I am using Google Advanced Rest Client for testing it and the output I am seeing is

```
Failed<br>
Array
(
    [message] => Authentication failed
)
```

I have added below rule to my Apache webserver

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add link to PDO Authenticatior you're using?

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov I followed both of them: https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth#usage-with-pdo, http://www.appelsiini.net/2014/slim-database-basic-authentication. The second one is detailed about PDO

Comment: Can you connect to database? How did you insert the users to database, ie did you hash the password before inserting it to database?

Comment: Yes I could connect to the database. But I didnt hash the password as I was testing it. Is it required to hash it?

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I hashed the password. But is that mandatory to hash the password?

Comment: Yes. You should absolutely never ever store cleartext passwords in database.

Comment: It's not that I would be storing passwords in plain text but I had the hashed module disabled while testing. Does pdo authenticator works on hashed passwords only?

Comment: Yes hashed passwords only. If you want to use cleartext passwords you must write your own authenticator as Werner suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mika Tuupola helped me resolve this problem in the comments and credit goes to him, and I thought it would help somebody. I was hoping that he would answer it for me to mark it.

Passwords should be hashed for HTTPBasicAuthentication middleware to work.
Clear text passwords cannot be authenticated with PDO driver, however, if the configuration array has 'users' property, with a clear text password like below, will work which obviously wouldnt be the case in production.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "users" => [
        "root" => "t00r",
        "somebody" => "passw0rd"
    ]
]));
```

The GitHub documentation at https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth was good enough to use this middleware however when it mentioned about clear text passwords, quote -

> Cleartext passwords are only good for quick testing. You probably...

I went ahead testing it with clear text passwords with PDO and it didnt work till the password is hashed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to pass your database naming scheme to the PdoAuthenticator as described in the [blog post](http://www.appelsiini.net/2014/slim-database-basic-authentication).

In your case this would be something like...

```
"authenticator" => new PdoAuthenticator([
    "pdo" => $pdo,
    "table" => "users",
    "user" => "user",
    "hash" => "hash"
])
```

...which indeed seem to be the default values. Maybe it's not working due to a simple underlying PDO connection problem. Also, looking at the [source](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/blob/2.x/src/HttpBasicAuthentication/PdoAuthenticator.php), the PdoAuthenticator uses password_verify() internally, so it will only be available in PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 and PHP 7.

You could also roll your own authenticator. As far as your question about handling the credentials in your own authenticator callback goes, you would do something like:

```
class MyAuthenticator implements AuthenticatorInterface {
    public function __invoke(array $arguments) {
        // $arguments['user'] will contain username
        // $arguments['password'] will contain password
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I indeed been through that but I wanted to test/use it once I am done with Pdo Authenticator. Custom Authentication might be an ideal solution for my requirement but nevertheless I would have an unresolved problem on hand.

Comment: By the way, what does this line mean **return (bool)rand(0,1);** ? Is this where we need to validate the credentials?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of using the supplied PdoAuthenticator in your case, since you are not going to write your own authenticator.

Comment: Do I need to mention table, user, hash values explicitly? I understood them as default values so I skipped them. Let me try

Comment: Looking at the source, that seems to be the case - you used the default values. Different values are applied internally using array_merge(): https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/blob/2.x/src/HttpBasicAuthentication/PdoAuthenticator.php. Why not just debug the authenticator's __invoke() method ? Could be as simple as a PDO connection problem?

Comment: Nope, it didnt work. I added the below snippet to check the connection. try {
 $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $dbUser,   $dbPassword);
 foreach($pdo->query('SELECT user, hash from users') as $row) {
  print_r($row);
 }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}

Comment: the above snippet gave this output: Array
(
    [user] => user
    [0] => user
    [hash] => password
    [1] => password
)
Failed<br>
Array
(
    [message] => Authentication failed
)

Comment: I couldnt understand the extra [0]=>user, [1]=>password in the output, though

Comment: Looking at the source, passwords are verified by the PdoAuthenticator via password_verify(). Are you using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 or PHP 7? I would suggest writing your own authenticator as a quick test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125912/discussion-between-werner-and-amruta-pani).

Comment: You only need to pass table name and / or columns is you use something else than default. Also the middleware has PHP requirement of ^5.5 || ^7.0 so composer will not even install if it op was using PHP 5.4.